# Retrofit:2.0.0-beta2, JacksonConverter with Joda DateTime

Tags: android, jackson, jodatime, retrofit2

I'm trying to use Retrofit2 with Jackson converter and Joda DateTime. The code that I have is the following:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.registerModule(new JodaModule());
retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(RestServiceApi.BASE_URL)
        .addConverterFactory(JacksonConverterFactory.create(mapper))
        .client(okHttpClient)
        .build();
```

However the Joda serializer/deserializer are not used resulting in

```
{
    ...........
    "DateTime": {
         "centuryOfEra": 20,
         "dayOfMonth": 29,
         "dayOfWeek": 2,
         "dayOfYear": 363,
         "era": 1,
         "hourOfDay": 8,
         .....
    }
 }
```

The same result is achieved when using JacksonConverterFactory.create() without ObjectMapper

```
   .addConverterFactory(JacksonConverterFactory.create())
```

In case the same ObjectMapper is used directly to write the value to String everything is working as expected.

```
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.registerModule(new JodaModule());
    String payload = mapper.writeValueAsString(message);
```

Any help will be appreciated.

**Edit:** 
Dependencies:

```
+--- com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.7.0
|    \--- com.squareup.okio:okio:1.6.0
+--- com.squareup.okhttp:logging-interceptor:2.7.0
|    \--- com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.7.0 (*)
+--- com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:2.0.0-beta2
|    \--- com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.5.0 -> 2.7.0 (*)
+--- com.squareup.retrofit:converter-jackson:2.0.0-beta2
|    +--- com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:2.0.0-beta2 (*)
|    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.4.3
|         +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.4.0
|         \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.4.3
+--- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-joda:2.4.3
|    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.4.0
|    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.4.3
|    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.4.3 (*)
|    \--- joda-time:joda-time:2.2 -> 2.3
+--- com.box:json-schema-validator:2.2.10
|    +--- joda-time:joda-time:2.3
```

**Edit2:** I removed the joda-time:2.3 dependency to no result.

Comment: Please provide exact versions of libraries you're using. Also note that the following example works as expected https://gist.github.com/miensol/e4e5fed9c36a75feb3cc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even with Retrofit2.0-beta3 I was not able to make the code above work.

I ended up using explicit serializer/deserializer on each field of DateTime type:

```
@JsonProperty("DateTime")
@NotNull
@JsonDeserialize(using = CustomDateTimeDeserializer.class)
@JsonSerialize(using = CustomDateTimeSerializer.class)
private Date DateTime;
```

Serializer code:

```
public class CustomDateTimeSerializer extends StdScalarSerializer<DateTime> {

public CustomDateTimeSerializer() {
    super(DateTime.class);
}

@Override
public void serialize(DateTime dateTime,
                      JsonGenerator jsonGenerator,
                      SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException, JsonGenerationException {
    DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss").withZone(DateTimeZone.forID("Europe/London"));
    String dateTimeAsString = fmt.print(dateTime);
    jsonGenerator.writeString(dateTimeAsString);
}
```

}

Deserializer code:

```
public class CustomDateTimeDeserializer extends StdScalarDeserializer<DateTime> {

public CustomDateTimeDeserializer() {
    super(DateTime.class);
}

@Override
public DateTime deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser,
                            DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
    JsonToken currentToken = jsonParser.getCurrentToken();
    if (currentToken == JsonToken.VALUE_STRING) {
        String dateTimeAsString = jsonParser.getText().trim();
        DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss").withZone(DateTimeZone.forID("Europe/London"));
        DateTime result = fmt.parseDateTime(dateTimeAsString);
        return result;
    }
    throw deserializationContext.mappingException(getValueClass());
}
```

}